# Anomaly detection in data transfer

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, anomaly-detection

I am working on a Anomaly detection model and would need help with identifying the anomalies in data transfer. Example: If an employee is connected using VPN and we have the following data usage:

```
 EMPID  date       Bytes_sent  Bytes recieved
 A123  Timestamp    222222     3333333
 A123  Timestamp    444444     6666666
 A123  Timestamp    99999999   88888888888
```

I want to flag row 3 as abnormal since the employee has been sending or receiving within a range and then there is a sudden jump. I want to keep track of the bytes sent and received in the recent days - meaning how his behavior is changing over the recent few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is keeping additional metrics for each observation:
For Bytes_recieved:

- An indicator of whether the observation is an outlier. This will be
  decided by whether the observed Bytes_recieved are outside of the
  last observed average plus, minus the last observed SD as described
  below.
- A running average over the last N non outlying events.
- Standard deviation over the last N non outlying events.

N will be based on the amount of observation you want to consider. You mentioned recent days, so  you could set `N = "recent" * average events per day`

E.g:

```
 EMPID date      Bytes_sent  Bytes_recieved  br-avg-last-N  br-sd-last-N  br-Outlier
 A123  Timestamp 222222      3333333         3333333        2357022.368  FALSE
 A123  Timestamp 444444      6666666         4999999.5      2356922.368  FALSE
 A123  Timestamp 99999999    88888888888     N/A            N/A          TRUE
```

Bytes_recieved Outlier for row three is calculated as whether the observed Bytes_recieved is outside the range defined by:

```
(last Bytes_recieved Average-Last-10) - 2*(last Bytes_recieved SD-Last-N) And (last Bytes_recieved Average-Last-10) + 2*(last Bytes_recieved SD-Last-N)
4999999.5 + 2 * 2356922.368 = 9713844.236; 9,713,844.236 < 88,888,888,888 -> TRUE
```

2 Standard deviations will give you 96% outliers, i.e. extreme observations you will only see ~4% of the time. You can modify it to your needs.

You can either do the same for Bytes_sent and have an 'Or' condition for the outlier decision, or calculate distance from a multi dimensional running average (here X is Bytes_sent and Y is Bytes_recieved) and mark outliers based on extreme distances. (You'll need to track a running SD or another spread metric per observation)
This way you could also easily add dimensions: time of day anomalies, extreme differences between Bytes_sent and Bytes_recieved etc.

Comment: Thank you Achervony